# React TS. Type 'Readonly<State>' is not an array type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have the following state

```
this.state = {
      notificationTypes: ["null", "astrix"]
    };
```

With the following interface

```
React.Component<IAppProps, State>

interface State {
  notificationTypes: Array<String>
}
```

I try to do modify the array, doing the following

```
changeTipoNotificaciones = value => {
    let lastChar = value[value.length - 1]
    if (lastChar === ",") {
      let newStr = value.slice(0, -1)
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        notificationTypes: [...prevState, newStr] //Type 'Readonly<State>' is not an array type. at ---prevState
      }))
    }
  }
```

But prevState gives the following error

> Type 'Readonly' is not an array type.

What am i missing?

Comment: share reproducable example

Comment: fixed with (prevState : any)

Comment: ...prevState.notificationTypes, you're not spreading the correct information